# How do I develop a completely custom portal/website that has rich designs in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, custom, sharepoint-framework

I am required to develop a fully custom knowledge management portal in SharePoint - where different team members in a project can login, ask directed questions, edit their profiles, contribute knowledge, etc. The rich bootstrap like designs I have been given is in no way close to the general SharePoint layout. I have just started understanding what SharePoint actually is and I am miserably confused as to where to begin, what version to use (SharePoint framework or Designer or others), how and where the coding would take place, will I need a database, etc.

Can you give a layout or a direction for development I can follow? Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Note: I don't have server OS for sharepoint-server.

Answer (score 0):

The [SharePoint look book](https://lookbook.microsoft.com/) is a great place to start for inspiration.

There is one that is based on [Microsoft 365 learning pathways](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/customlearning/custom_overview) which I think would be a great place to start when making a knowledge management portal.

You can customize these further using both out of the box web parts, or extend when needed using SharePoint Framework.

Hope this gets you started!

Answer (score 0):

I would either develop

- A SharePoint add-in - you still get a tiny SharePoint navigation bar (which you can hide with css). In such an app you get help to get the SharePoint context and using the users context and thus the permission the user has.
- A web app of your choice. Make calls to the SharePoint API using a service account or the user context (the latter may be tricky).

I would try to avoid using a separate database. If you store data in the SharePoint lists etc that would reduce the complexity of deployment etc.